# How do I create a generic List using abstract class?

Tags: c#, json, abstract-class, generic-list

I have a Json class "GetAllDevices()". My JSON response consists of an Array/List of objects, where each object has the below common properties.

```
public class GetAllDevices
{
    [JsonProperty("_id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("actions")]
    public Action[] Actions { get; set; }

    public class Action
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public Action_Def action_def { get; set; }
    }

    public class Action_Def
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to create 2 generic lists containing all the above properties based on its "type".
lstfoo1 List contains all the properties(_id, name type and actions) where type="foo1". Similarly, lstfoo2 is a List which contains the above properties where type="foo2".

What I have done so far:

```
string strJson=getJSON();
Foo1 lstfoo1=new Foo1();
Foo2 lstfoo2=new Foo2();
List<Foo1> foo1list= lstfoo1.GetDeviceData(strJson);
List<Foo2> foo2list = lstfoo2.GetDeviceData(strJson);


public class AllFoo1: GetAllDevices
{
}

public class AllFoo2: GetAllDevices
{
}

public abstract class HomeDevices<T>
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public List<AllFoo1> lstfoo1{ get; set; }
    public List<AllFoo2> lstfoo2{ get; set; }
    public abstract List<T> GetDeviceData(string jsonResult);
}

public class Foo1: HomeDevices<AllFoo1>
{
    public Foo1()
    {
        type = "foo1";
    }

    public override List<AllFoo1> GetDeviceData(string jsonResult)
    {
        var lst =Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AllFoo1>>(jsonResult);
        var lst1 = lst.Where(x => x.Type.Equals(type)).ToList();
        return lst1;
    }
}

public class Foo2: HomeDevices<AllFoo2>
{
    public Foo2()
    {
        type = "foo2";
    }

    public override List<AllFoo2> GetDeviceData(string jsonResult)
    {
        var lst = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AllFoo2>>(jsonResult);
        var lst1 = lst.Where(x => x.Type.Equals(type)).ToList();
        return lst1;
    }
}
```

My question is, is there an easier way to do this using abstract classes? Can I directly convert my "GetAllDevices" class into an abstract class and inherit it and deserialize into it and create a generic list?

Comment: The implementation of `GetDeviceData` looks exactly the same. Can't you just implement it on the base class and use T as a parameter on the call to `DeserializeObject`?

Comment: Yes you can create a List< baseclass > and put objects of either type into it, but it sounds like you are trying to put properties of the objects into the list and not the objects themselves, is that right? In that case you can just use List< object >. You can always use `getType` to differentiate between property types.

Comment: I'm guessing he wants type enforcement on the list

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard I want to be able to access all the properties of each object. I am extremely new to using abstract classes. I have seen various examples but not sure how to fit mine in them. Could you provide me a link or something?

Comment: @JuanR Could you tell me how to do that or point me to a link?

Comment: @V_stack: It seems you have implemented a `type` property as an attempt to keep track of the type of object you are dealing with. This is not necessary. I would recommend instead that you use concrete classes that represent each device and use the `GetType()` method to selectively choose.

Comment: @V_stack: I posted an answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be simple enough to move the implementation of method `GetDeviceData()` to the base class.

For this to work, you will need to add a constraint on `T` so the compiler knows a bit more about the base type. You will also need to implement a constructor to populate the concrete type's `type` string you use around. This is a necessary measure to ensure the value is always populated as it is used for comparison in the method in question:

```
public abstract class HomeDevices<T> where T: GetAllDevices
{
    public HomeDevices(string concreteType)
    {
        type = concreteType;
    }

    public string type { get; set; }
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public List<AllFoo1> lstfoo1 { get; set; }
    public List<AllFoo2> lstfoo2 { get; set; }

    //This method is now generic and works for both.
    public List<T> GetDeviceData(string jsonResult)
    {
        var lst = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(jsonResult);
        var lst1 = lst.Where(x => x.Type.Equals(type)).ToList();
        return lst1;
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: This did help, thanks! Also, could you tell me if I dont plan on creating 2 different lists, is using abstract class necessary?

Comment: @V_stack: An abstract class is meant to be shared by concrete classes. It really depends on your design. I usually start with interfaces and concrete classes, then introduce abstract (base) classes when I realize I have more specialized versions of things. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This should help, if I understand your problem correctly. Let me know if you have questions or it doesn't work as you need. I put this together really quickly without testing.

The way the Type property is defined could be improved but I left it as you had it.

```
public class MyApplication
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        string json = getJSON();
        DeviceTypeOne foo1 = new DeviceTypeOne();
        DeviceTypeTwo foo2 = new DeviceTypeTwo();
        IList<DeviceTypeOne> foo1Results = foo1.GetDeviceData(json); // calls GetDeviceData extension method
        IList<DeviceTypeTwo> foo2Results = foo2.GetDeviceData(json); // calls GetDeviceData extension method
    }        
}

// implemented GetDeviceData as extension method of DeviceBase, instead of the abstract method within DeviceBase,
// it's slightly cleaner than the abstract method
public static class DeviceExtensions
{
    public static IList<T> GetDeviceData<T>(this T device, string jsonResult) where T : DeviceBase
    {
        IEnumerable<T> deviceDataList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<T>>(jsonResult);
        IEnumerable<T> resultList = deviceDataList.Where(x => x.Type.Equals(typeof(T).Name));
        return resultList.ToList();
    }
}

// abstract base class only used to house common properties and control Type assignment
public abstract class DeviceBase : IDeviceData
{
    protected DeviceBase(string type)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(type)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));}

        Type = type; // type's value can only be set by classes that inherit and must be set at construction time
    }
    [JsonProperty("_id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; private set;} 
    [JsonProperty("actions")]
    public DeviceAction[] Actions { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceTypeOne : DeviceBase
{
    public DeviceTypeOne() : base(nameof(DeviceTypeOne))
    {
    }
}

public class DeviceTypeTwo : DeviceBase
{
    public DeviceTypeTwo() : base(nameof(DeviceTypeTwo))
    {
    }
}

// implemented GetAllDevices class as IDeviceData interface
public interface IDeviceData
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Type { get; }
    DeviceAction[] Actions { get; set; }
}

// renamed and relocated class Action to DeviceAction
public class DeviceAction
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DeviceActionDefinition DeviceActionDefinition { get; set; }
}

// renamed and relocated Action_Def to DeviceActionDefinition
public class DeviceActionDefinition
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why we are using an abstract class as well as an Interface? Also, My json class is a list/array of devices and has many more properties than just the id,name and actions. But the important thing to know is, all those properties are common to all devices. So my thought was to convert the entire "GetAllDevices" as an abstract class.

Comment: I kept the abstract base class since you already had one and it allows the type to be controlled on construction. You could forego the IDeviceData interface, but I added it with the thought you may need to persist the data and the interface can help when passing it between application layers.

Comment: Where exactly are you using DeviceExtension's method?

Comment: I mean, where exactly are you calling it? Im sorry if I am asking basic questions, Im still learning.

Comment: I'm calling it on this line... IList<DeviceTypeOne> foo1Results = foo1.GetDeviceData(json);... I'll add some comments to my post. Extension methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods